# Why is my variable not receiving the right value from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter. I need to get just one value from Firestore and update it for all users. So I use a `listen` to keep the value updated. I receive the value in one variable but I can't use it outside the `listen` method.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class PaginaGraficos extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaginaGraficosState createState() => _PaginaGraficosState();
}
 
class _PaginaGraficosState extends State<PaginaGraficos> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    String _totalGeradoApp = "0";
 
    _getTotalGeradoApp () {
      Firestore.instance.collection("dados_app").snapshots().listen(
              ( snapshot ){
            var totalGeradoApp;
            for( DocumentSnapshot item in snapshot.documents ){
              var dados = item.data;
              totalGeradoApp = dados["total_gerado_app"];
              print("totalGeradoApp: $totalGeradoApp");
            }
            _totalGeradoApp = totalGeradoApp;
          }
      );
    }
    
    _getTotalGeradoApp();
    print("_totalGeradoApp: $_totalGeradoApp");
 
    return Container(
      child: Text("$_totalGeradoApp"),
    );
  }
}
```

Some names are in Portuguese because I'm Brasilian but the code is still understandable.
I'm new with Dart so please tell me if I'm doing something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `function` passed to the `listen` method will execute whenever the value is updated, but the rest of the code runs only once. So, if you want the the `Text` in the container to be updated whenever the value is updated - use a `StreamBuilder`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("dados_app").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        
        if(!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('Loading...');
        }

        // update _totalGeradoApp
        var totalGeradoApp;
        var docs = (snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot).documents;
        for(var item in docs) {
          var dados = item.data;
          totalGeradoApp = dados["total_gerado_app"];
        }
        _totalGeradoApp = totalGeradoApp;

        // return Text Widget with updated text
        return Text("$_totalGeradoApp");
    ),
  );
}
```

So, in your code the `listen`er is added to the `stream` and immediately the next code is executed where a `Container` is created with `_totalGeradoApp`, which was `"0"` initially. Whenever the value was updated `_totalGeradoApp` is updated but the text in the `Container` is not. By using a `StreamBuilder` the `Text` widget is also updated whenever a new value is available.